# SFML render window not appearing when running program

Tags: c++, sfml, clion

When attempting to run a program that is intended to bring forth a render window generated through the SFML library, it will successfully compile but refuse to actually launch a window. After several hours of debugging, I am unable to find where I may have potentially gone wrong in the code, and am now beginning to think it is a problem through my IDE (CLion). Nevertheless, the code used for the render window will be provided.

```
int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    // Create the main window
    sf::RenderWindow* window = new sf::RenderWindow(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "SFML window");
#ifdef SHAPE
    sf::Shape s = sf::Shape::Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100, sf::Color::Blue);
#else
    sf::Image img; img.create(100, 100, sf::Color::Blue);
    sf::Texture t; t.loadFromImage(img);
    sf::Sprite s(t);

#endif

// Start the game loop
while (window->isOpen())
{
    // Process events
    sf::Event event;
    while (window->pollEvent(event))
    {
        // Close window : exit
        if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            window->close();


        if (event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed)
            if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Escape)
                window->close();
            else {
                delete window;
                window = new sf::RenderWindow(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "SFML window");
            }

    }

    // Clear screen
    window->clear();

    s.rotate(30.0);

    window->draw(s);

    // Update the window
    window->display();
}

delete window;

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

#endif
```

Comment: What OS are you using? Windows has some peculiarities regarding whether the program is a "console" program or a window. This may not be your issue (I only remember seeing issues where the console is hidden, not the GUI) but it's probably worth exploring if it applies to you...

Comment: Additionally, for what it's worth, I would recommend fully bracing your `if`s and `else`s. The current code uses a mixture of one-line and braced styles, which makes it very difficult to debug. This might be particularly relevant given that you destroy and re-create the window in one of the cases of your event-loop.

Answer (score 0):

One of the most common issue with CLion users and launching an application is that they forget to provide the necessary SFML DLLs, so the application never starts but closes with a return value `0xC0000135`.

If you launch the executable directly via explorer, you'll get the more well-known message box which tells you which DLL exactly is missing.

The solution is to copy the necessary DLLs next to your executable in the CLion's output directory.